# How to use tlb files in a native C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, com, visual-studio-2005

I have a tlb files that contains some function declaration that I need to use.

If I use

```
#import "type_library.tlb"
```

I can correclty reference the function from my code:

```
tlb_namespace::required_function();
```

But when I compile the project the linker says that tlb_namespace::required_function is an unresolved external symbol.

How can I succesfully build this kind of project?

**EDIT**:

I have used the same type library in a Dummy VBA access project. I have added the reference to the type library and I have noticed that some of the function contained in the type library are correctly called. But some of them are not. VBA says It can't locate their entry point in the related dll.

Can this  explain the unresolved external symbol when building c++ app?

I have also noticed that the failing function are declared in the tlb like this:

```
UPPER_function_name
```

but in the dll are declared like this:

```
Upper_function_name
```

Can this be the issue?

Is it possible to solve this kind of error directly modifying the binary tlb file or dll?

Comment: is `#import "type_library.tlb"` the only #import directive fro this tlb in your project. Does it reside in the same cpp as function call? How is `required_function` defined in the generated .tlh and .tli files?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic The project for now is a very simple one so the #import is just one and it reside in the same .cpp file of the call. I have tried to generate .tlh and .tli files... they appear only if I go to project property\Preprocessor Generate Preprocessed file. However I probably don't add them in a correct mode to the project because if I do I get another linker error.

Comment: you don't have to add them. They will be created during build in your release/debug folder, so look them up there.

Comment: Files are created but now linker says: "can't found .\Debug\stdafx.obj

Comment: you have some other issues, obviously. try to rebuild all, if there are still errors, post full build log. it is hard to tell this way

Comment: Watching closely I don't get a .tli file, just two .i files

Answer (score 5):

Use IDE to view TLB information.
Use this help : [How to: View Type Library Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98w057c3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

At IDE : View-> Object Browser, click "..." Edit Custom Component Set, browse your TLB file and Add to view information.

Confirm namespace used for.

Comment: Sorry for the late feedback. If I open the tlb file in the object browser I see it as a library containing a single namespace which contains a number of modules that group some functions. When I #import the tlb in a native C++ project I get a namespace containing only function. As I said before adding a reference to the tlb in a VBA project allows me to call the functions, but in a native C++ project I get linker error.

Answer (score 0):

use the namespace to resolve the linker error:
example:
 #import "<>" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace <>

this will resolve the problem