# Cannot open source file mscorlib.tlh

Tags: c++, .net-core, import, c++-cli, mscorlib

I am trying to import "mscorlib.tlb" inside my C++ project, but I keep getting this error:

```
cannot open source file "C:/Users/MyUsername/source/repos/DLL_Loader/.net compatibility/mscorlib.tlh
```

I am trying to import it this way:

```
#import "mscorlib.tlb"
```

just like MSDN suggests to do (https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-reference-net-types-from-com).

I am quite lost here, I never imported a .tlb file before, so I have no idea if I am missing some steps or something.

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57751715/4386278, though the answer there is kinda sh!+

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381440/how-to-use-tlb-files-in-a-native-c-project, here is another option for you

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I didn't understand half a sentence of that answer, I made this thread looking for better ones, in all honesty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C:/ is already the highest position in a Windows file system, C:/../ does most likely not go where you want to be.

It seems your include path is messed up and maybe you have to remove the C: to make it a relative path.

Comment: My bad, I wrote the path in the wrong way inside the question, the correct path is: C:/Users/MyUsername/source/repos/DLL_Loader/.net compatibility/mscorlib.tlh.

Comment: OK, can happen. So, where _is_ this file that you are missing? Please search the whole computer for it (using the Explorer)!

Comment: For some weird reason restarting Visual Studio worked, so I guess problem solved?

Comment: Yeah, get used to it. switching it off and on again will always be the first thing to try! :-)